# Is it true: plants, that keep snakes away?

Tags: planting

Someone told me, that there is a plant, that keeps away snakes and other lizards. All you have to do is plant it near the fences and the house.
Is it true and if yes, what is that plant?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

According to some research there is plants that act like snake repellent. Just keep in mind they are not guaranteed to work but here are a few plants that can help keep them away. In order from best to least --> Wormwood (Artemisia), Tulbaghia Violacea, West Indian lemon grass (Cymbopogon citratus), Sarpgandha (Rauwolfia serpentia) and, Andrographis paniculata.

The Tulbaghia Violacea is very good snake repellent but have some other uses as well. The smell this flower gives off repels fleas, ticks and mosquitoes, but only were the plant has been crushed (or a rip in leaf). The fresh bulbs could also be boiled and the decoction can be used as a orally to clear up coughs and colds.

West Indian Leomon grass, the snakes do not like the citrus smell from the leaves.

You could also make a garlic mixture and spray that in places to help repel the snakes as well. It is 10 bulbs (purple is the best as they are very potent), 4 Table spoons of garlic oil or any other vegetable oil, and some water.

For preparation....
1. Take the blender and add some water. 2. Separate the garlic into cloves and add them to the blender. 3. Start blending it until a smooth nice paste is formed, then add the oil. 4. Leave the mixture in a plastic container for an hour with the lid on. 5. Now it is ready, and place a few drops in any srea you don't want snakes to be seen. Repeat the process after it rains.
The mixture usually lasts for at least three weeks, then you need to make a new batch.

Comment: do you have any references about whether any of these work?  All I could find was lots of "I found this worked..."

Comment: I am thinking of using lemon grass because the snakes can smell this. where our lemon grass is planted, there are almost never a snake hiding.

Comment: Can you show a reference or research that proves your point?

Comment: The lemon grass is from my personal experience and I can not re-find the page where I have gotten my research.